# Variables globales en NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Buen día, recién comienzo un proyecto de NetCore y quisiera saber  ¿Como puedo hacer uso de una variable global en todas las vistas?

La cuestión es que mi solución se llama "Gastos" sin embargo el nombre que muestro al usuario en el Navbar, menú y algunas otras partes (vistas) es "Armenta", sin embargo este ultimo aun no esta definido del todo, puede darse el caso en que este cambie en las siguientes semanas. ¿Es posible colocar este valor en un archivo de configuración y obtener dicho valor desde cualquier vista? o ¿Que otra alternativa tengo?

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, hay que aclarar que en C# no existe nada como las *variables globales*.

En segundo lugar, guardar un valor como configuración global sí que es posible, y lo mejor es que es muy sencillo de hacer:

1. En el **Explorador de soluciones** da clic derecho a tu proyecto (no a la *Solución*) y ve a la opción "**Propiedades**".
2. En la pestaña de propiedades, selecciona la opción "**Recursos**" del menú del lado izquierdo. Si te aparece la leyenda de *"Este proyecto no contiene un archivo de recursos predeterminado"*, dale clic para crearlo.
3. Visual Studio te mostrará un pequeño menú en la parte superior (dentro de la misma pestaña de *Propiedades*), asegúrate de que el primer botón indique "*Cadenas*" y que el resto del espacio esté ocupado por una matriz con las columnas "**Nombre**", "**Valor**" y "**Comentario**".
4. En la matriz, da un nombre a tu valor (por ejemplo, `AppTitle`) y asígnale el valor que quieres (en este caso, `Armenta`). No es necesario el comentario.
5. Para acceder a este valor desde el código, es tan sencillo como esta sentencia: `Properties.Resources.AppTitle` (si no te lo da en automático IntelliSense, puedes probar con esta: `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("AppTitle")`).

   En WPF:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.Title = Properties.Resources.AppTitle;
   }
   ```

   En Forms:

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       Text = Properties.Resources.AppTitle;
   }
   ```

   En web:

   ```
   <title>@TuNamespace.Properties.Resources.AppTitle</title>
   ```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Kroneaux Schneider, adicional  en el paso 3  en el menú que mencionas el modificador de acceso por default es Internal, para poder acceder al recurso lo he vuelto publico y con eso basto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Podrias usar la configuracion de `asp.net core` inyectando en el controller esa seccion, no se si has leido sobre el `IOptions<>`

[Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

podrias definir en el `appsettings.json` algo como ser

```
"Navbar": {
    "Titulo": "Gastos"
 }
```

entonces si defines la class

```
public class NavbarOptions{
   public string Titulo {get;set;}
}
```

podrias inyectar esa seccion si la configuras

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<PositionOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Navbar"));

}
```

en el controller quedaria

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly NavbarOptions _options;

    public Test2Model(IOptions<NavbarOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content($"Titulo: {_options.Titulo});
    }
}
```

En cada controller que necesites ese dato solo defines el options en el constructor y el dato se inyecta directamente

Comment: Gracias  por  tu ayuda  Leandro, es una buena  opción